# Why Contributors can approve pages?

Tags: 2007

We have a MOSS 2007 publishing website that uses Serial Aprpoval workflow for content approval.

I have created Approvers and Contributors SP groups and use AD groups to manager group members.

Approvers are assigned Approve permission and Contributors are assigned Contribute permission.

Everything is out of the box. The problem is that when an approval request is sent to a Contributor, the Contributor can see the necessary UI and approve the page.

I double checked on user's group assignment and permissions, nothing out of line. What can be wrong?

**UPDATE**

I found a [solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/34fbbeab-3a4a-4836-b31f-732cc39bd2b6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the [answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/34fbbeab-3a4a-4836-b31f-732cc39bd2b6).

Comment: Ray, would you mind editing your post to include the answer? It could help other people if they run into a similar issue.